# Aligning div content vertical center doesn't work

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I read many answers about vertical align of content in divs, and tried to implement the major answer that I saw:

```
.middle-col{
   vertical-align: middle; 
   display: table-cell;

}
```

But it doesn't work.

See http://jsfiddle.net/aKybp/4/.

Since it's built based on bootstrap, you would need to expand left the result of the HTML to see the div

What I am trying to achieve is - to align vertically center the content of the middle column

Comment: Just a tip, instead of copying the whole CSS of Bootstrap to your fiddles, you can include it as an external resource from http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/

Comment: Well, It's condensed vertically so there is no empty space in which it could center. Unless you've mistaked vertical for horizontal.

Comment: @bootstrapcdn what is the URL?

Comment: http://www.bootstrapcdn.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your middle column was inside another container that did not spread to the full height.
The following settings fix that (also the `.middle-col` element was merged with its parent).

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/aKybp/5/)

```
.middle-col {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.row > .col-md-6, .row > .col-md-3 {
    display: table-cell;
    float: none;
}
```

- P.S - The selectors I'm using here are really general, it's advisable that you make them more specific by using ID's or something similar.

Comment: Thanks looks good, but what do you mean by your comment? where shall I add a specific id?

Comment: The selector I've used (`.row > .col-md-6, .row > .col-md-3`) will affect every element with class `.col-md-3/6` that is a direct child of `.row` in your site. I'm assuming you want to change this behavior only on this specific container, so give their container some ID and use it on the CSS.

Comment: Okay, so maybe add a class (lets say `.equal-height` to the containers instead of an ID and change the selector to be something like `.equal-height .row > .col-md-6, .equal-height .row > .col-md-3`

Comment: What do you mean by containers? is row the container?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37829/discussion-between-odelya-and-itay)

Answer (score 0):

Your div container actually "is" aligning the text vertically. Your problem is, that the div container's height is no bigger than the text content it wraps.

To achieve a vertical centering of the text relative to the image, you need to set the div-container's height to e.g. 480px (the image's height).

```css
.middle-col {
    vertical-align: middle; 
    display: table-cell;
    height: 480px;
}
```